# Converting Latex to String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, latex, mathquill

Is there a library that supports conversion from Latex to maths string?

eg. I need to convert `\frac{10}{3x+3}=5x^2` to something like `(10/(3*x+3))=5*(x**2)`

(I get Latex from MathQuill)

Comment: https://www.mathjax.org/

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/Crownie/latex-to-js

example `\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}`

convert `(d)/(dx)sqrt(x)`

Your example can be convert to `(10)/(3x+3)=pow(5x,2)`

but I don't know what it's limitation.